# Vectorize a for loop in numpy to calculate duct-tape overlaping

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, numba

I'm creating an application with python to calculate duct-tape overlapping (modeling a dispenser applies a product on a rotating drum).

I have a program that works correctly, but is really slow. I'm looking for a solution to optimize a `for` loop used to fill a numpy array. Could someone help me vectorize the code below?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some parameters
width = 264
bbddiam = 940
accuracy = 4 #2 points per pixel

drum = np.zeros(accuracy**2 * width * bbddiam).reshape((bbddiam * accuracy , width * accuracy))

# The "slow" function
def line_mask(drum, coef, intercept, upper=True, accuracy=accuracy):
    """Masks a half of the array"""
    to_return = np.zeros(drum.shape)
    for index, v in np.ndenumerate(to_return):
        if upper == True:
            if index[0] * coef + intercept > index[1]:
                to_return[index] = 1
        else:
            if index[0] * coef + intercept <= index[1]:
                to_return[index] = 1
    return to_return


def get_band(drum, coef, intercept, bandwidth):
    """Calculate a ribbon path on the drum"""
    to_return = np.zeros(drum.shape)
    t1 = line_mask(drum, coef, intercept + bandwidth / 2, upper=True)
    t2 = line_mask(drum, coef, intercept - bandwidth / 2, upper=False)
    to_return = t1 + t2
    return np.where(to_return == 2, 1, 0)

single_band = get_band(drum, 1 / 10, 130, bandwidth=15)

# Visualize the result !
plt.imshow(single_band)
plt.show()
```

Numba does wonders for my code, reducing runtime from 5.8s to 86ms  (special thanks to @Maarten-vd-Sande):

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def line_mask(drum, coef, intercept, upper=True, accuracy=accuracy):
    ...
```

A better solution with numpy is still welcome ;-)

Comment: you can always just try using numba and keep what you have :)

Comment: Indeed, numba loves loops ! I will give a try

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande, The results are impressive with numba --> the execution time goes from 5.8 sec. to 86 msec. !! Thank you

Comment: No time to put together a full answer, but based on what calculation does over and over, I'd look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html (including numpy.sum and numpy.prod) to do matrix operations quickly and the logic functions for your comparisons ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html)

Comment: Not sure if pure numpy will beat numba, but this can be done with proper numpy fairly simply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for any looping at all here. You have effectively two different `line_mask` functions. Neither needs to be looped explicitly, but you would probably get a significant speedup just from rewriting it with a pair of `for` loops in an `if` and `else`, rather than an `if` and `else` in a `for` loop, which gets evaluated many many times.

The really numpythonic thing to do is to properly vectorize your code to operate on entire arrays without any loops. Here is a vectorized version of `line_mask`:

```
def line_mask(drum, coef, intercept, upper=True, accuracy=accuracy):
    """Masks a half of the array"""
    r = np.arange(drum.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)
    c = np.arange(drum.shape[1]).reshape(1, -1)
    comp = c.__lt__ if upper else c.__ge__
    return comp(r * coef + intercept)
```

Setting up the shapes of `r` and `c` to be `(m, 1)` and `(n, 1)` so that the result is `(m, n)` is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), and is the staple of vectorization in numpy.

The result of the updated `line_mask` is a boolean mask (as the name implies) rather than a float array. This makes it smaller, and hopefully bypasses float operations entirely. You can now rewrite `get_band` to use masking instead of addition:

```
def get_band(drum, coef, intercept, bandwidth):
    """Calculate a ribbon path on the drum"""
    t1 = line_mask(drum, coef, intercept + bandwidth / 2, upper=True)
    t2 = line_mask(drum, coef, intercept - bandwidth / 2, upper=False)
    return t1 & t2
```

The remainder of the program should stay the same, since these functions preserve all the interfaces.

If you want, you can rewrite most of your program in three (still somewhat legible) lines:

```
coeff = 1/10
intercept = 130
bandwidth = 15

r, c = np.ogrid[:drum.shape[0], :drum.shape[1]]
check = r * coeff + intercept
single_band = ((check + bandwidth / 2 > c) & (check - bandwidth /  2 <= c))
```

Comment: --> 62.6 msec. , Thanks a lot !

Comment: @LaurentR. Neat. I bet the three-liner I just added will be even faster, but probably not by much.

Comment: @LaurentR. Always neat to see numpy beating numba, in my opinion. Proper numba is an unstoppable beast.

Comment: Did not know about `__lt__` and `__ge__` operators on ndarrays - thank you!

Comment: @Jeff. Yup. Any operator you use in Python like `<`, `>=`, `in`, etc, is implemented via a magic class method, which you can bind to that instance. `type(x).__lt__(x, y)`, `type(x).__ge__(x, y)` and `type(x).__contains__(x, y)` would be called for `x < y`, `x >= y` and `y in x`, respectively. That's true for any python object, including arrays.